# Synchronize files based only on the existence of unique filenames (Mac OS / Unix)

Tags: macos, command-line, unix

I am looking for a way to synchronize two folders/volumes based only on whether a filename exists in folder A but not in folder B.  I want the sync to completely ignore path and modification dates.  Any new uniques files can be moved to some designated folder.

As an example, let's say Folder A contains a complicated directory structure with multiple folders and a total of 5,000 files.  So there are maybe a few dozen folders, sometimes with folders inside them, and files spread out in those folders at random. Now folder B contains 4,500 files in a different folder structure – the paths of the files in Folder A have nothing to do with the paths in Folder B.

So what I want to do is scan through all 5,000 filenames in Folder A and its subfolders and check them against the filenames in Folder B and its subfolders.  If there is a matching name somewhere in Folder B, the file is ignored.  If a filename exists in Folder A somewhere, but not anywhere in Folder B, then the file is copied to a new folder inside Folder B – let's call it "NewFiles".

So when the process is done, I will know that Folder B contains all the same filenames as Folder A.  It might contain more files than Folder A, but any filename in Folder A will also exist in Folder B.

The important thing here is that the synchronization completely ignores path and modification date.  All that matters is the filename itself, independent of path.

Eventually, this would be most useful if I could scan say 3 volumes and compare the filenames to what is on a different 2 volumes.  So "folder A" would become a group of drives and "folder B" would become a separate group of drives.   But for the time being, we can stick to just two folders to make the question simpler.

Any thoughts?

thanks!